# Postgres temporal data and CREATE table syntax

Tags: postgresql, syntax, timestamp, precision, intervals

I have a CSV file from a 3rd party and I want to create a Postgres table for.
There are a couple of columns with timestamp style information but with differing levels of precision.
Here is some sample data of two of the fields
"issued"
2012-05-07 04:04:05
"reportedtime"
2012-05-12 00:00:00.571395

There is also another field which is "duration" and has data like
90 days, 0:00:00
Is there a Postgres data type for this too?

What would the syntax be that I would need to create a table using these fields:

CREATE TABLE blah (
issued ????,
reportedtime ????,
duration ???
);

NOTE: I'm already familiar with this part:

COPY blah (issued, reportedtime, duration) FROM path to file WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

Just don't want that to bomb when I run because stored data does not match table column types.

Comment: I think the duration is an INTERVAL type and the other two are TIMESTAMP (WITHOUT TIME ZONE). But the precision 'p' they point to is buried somewhere in the postgres docs... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: They also mention. Quote:  The allowed range of p is from 0 to 6 for the timestamp and interval types. But fail to indicate what 0 thru 6 represent - documentation sucks!

Comment: Why using very old documentation? Version 8.1 is OEL for a almost 2 years.

Comment: @JGFMK: I went to look at the (ancient) referenced documentation, and the first place I found a description of `p` it said: "where p in the optional precision specification is an integer corresponding to the number of fractional digits in the seconds field." What would make that more clear for you? Or, if there's some page which isn't as specific, could you check the corresponding page in a supported release and see if it's still missing, and post a reference to that specific page, so it can be fixed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `timestamptz` and `interval` types ([documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html)). I've used timezone-aware type as I always do so, it gives more freedom in later data manipulaition.

```sql
CREATE TABLE blah (
    issued timestamptz,
    reportedtime timestamptz,
    duration interval);

COPY blah FROM stdin;
2012-05-07 04:04:05 2012-05-12 00:00:00.571395  90 days, 0:00:00
\.

SELECT * FROM blah;
```